# Streamed encrypt then MAC construction

Tags: python, security, cryptography

I've been porting python Keyczar to work under 2to3 conversion ([Github](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-python2to3)). I wanted to consolidate its streaming AES encrypt/decrypt backend interface with its string decrypt/encrypt. So I wrote a new implementation using `io.BufferReader` and `io.BufferedWriter`. In my construction, I decrypt up until the last block and then check the MAC before decrypting that block and unpadding.

I feel a bit unsure of whether this is the right thing to do, as it's not my typical construction, and whether instead I should just buffer the whole thing and not decrypt at all until the MAC is checked.

I'm not a Python developer so any API or idiomatic suggestions are very welcome too.

These snippets are covered under the Apache license, follow the links to see whole code.

**[Encrypt](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-python2to3/blob/master/python/keyczar/keys.py#L456)**

```
 def EncryptIO(self, reader , writer):
    """
    Write ciphertext byte stream containing Header|IV|Ciph|Sig.
    """    
    mac = self.hmac_key.CreateStreamable()

    #Write and update mac for header
    header = self.Header()
    writer.write(header)
    mac.Update(header)

    #Generate, write, and update mac for IV
    iv_bytes = util.RandBytes(self.block_size)
    writer.write(iv_bytes)
    mac.Update(iv_bytes)

    buffer_size = self.block_size * 4
    cipher = self.__CreateCipher(self.key_bytes, iv_bytes)
    more = True
    while more:
      data = util.ReadLength(reader, buffer_size)
      more = len(data) == buffer_size

      if not more:
        data = self._Pad(data)

      #encrypt, update mac and write out ciphertext
      ciph_bytes = cipher.encrypt(data)
      mac.Update(ciph_bytes)
      writer.write(ciph_bytes)

    #call final mac and write whatever is returned
    ciph_bytes = cipher.final()
    mac.Update(ciph_bytes)
    writer.write(ciph_bytes)

    #write mac and flush
    writer.write(mac.Sign())
    writer.flush()
```

**[Decrypt](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-python2to3/blob/master/python/keyczar/keys.py#L502)**

```
  def DecryptIO(self, header, reader, writer):
    mac = self.hmac_key.CreateStreamable()

    #update mac of header
    mac.Update(header)
    #read out iv and update mac
    iv_bytes = util.ReadLength(reader, self.block_size)
    mac.Update(iv_bytes)

    cipher = self.__CreateCipher(self.key_bytes, iv_bytes)

    more = True
    # buffer_size is a block multiple -- req'd
    buffer_size = self.block_size * 4 
    # read out one more byte into starting tag buff
    # so on a valid ciphertext we will know we are on 
    # the last block to unpad
    initial_len = util.HLEN + 1
    tagbuff = util.ReadLength(reader, initial_len)

    while more:
      buff = util.ReadLength(reader, buffer_size)
      more = len(buff) == buffer_size
      tempbuff = tagbuff + buff
      if more:
        buff = tempbuff[:buffer_size]
        tagbuff = tempbuff[buffer_size:]
      else:
        buff = tempbuff[:-util.HLEN]
        tagbuff = tempbuff[-util.HLEN:]
      mac.Update(buff)
      if not more:
        #check the mac before we try and finish decryption
        calctag = mac.Sign()
        if not util.ConstantTimeCompare(tagbuff, calctag):
          raise errors.InvalidSignatureError()
      ptext = cipher.decrypt(buff)
      if not more:
        #remove padding now that we know the ciphertext is valid
        ptext += cipher.final()
        ptext = self._UnPad(ptext)
      writer.write(ptext)
      writer.flush()
```